# FileReader not reading entire text file

Tags: java, input, inputstream, filereader, txt

I want my code to read a txt file and print out each line, but nearly half of the lines are being skipped over seeming randomly. How do I ensure the entire file is read?

```
        BufferedInputStream readIt = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pBase));
        //pBase is txt File object
        Scanner actualRead = new Scanner(readIt);

    
        while(actualRead.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Line is : " + actualRead.nextLine());
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use one of the nio utility methods, such as [`readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)).

For large files that you don't want to load into memory all at once, you can use the [`lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) method like so:

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
...
try (var lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(pBase))) {
  lines.forEach(l -> {
    System.out.println(l);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively..scanner can take a file parameter as input...

```java
Scanner actualRead = new Scanner(pBase); //directly pass the file as argument...
//Although this threatens to throw an IOException..catch  it in try-catch or add to throws...
try {
  Scanner actualRead = new Scanner(pBase);
  while (actualRead.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("Line is : " + actualRead.nextLine());
}
catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("err...");
```